# Can Only Upload Arduino Sketch Once to Custom Mega2560 Board

Tags: arduino-mega, bootloader, atmega2560, firmware, atmega16u2

I created a custom Arduino based off the Mega2560 R3. It uses the ATMega16U2 uC as the USB interface between ATMega2560 uC and the PC.

The bootloader on the 2560 is uploaded by using an Arduino Micro via ArduinoISP. I followed this [tutorial from Instructables](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Restore-the-Arduino-UNO-R3-ATmega16U2-Firmw/) on uploading the bootloader/firmware for the 16U2 except I modified some parts for the 2560 instead of the UNO. Here is my added section in the /program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/boards.txt

```
unorestore.name=MEGA2560 16U2 Restore Firmware
unorestore.bootloader.tool=arduino:avrdude
unorestore.bootloader.low_fuses=0xff
unorestore.bootloader.high_fuses=0xd9
unorestore.bootloader.extended_fuses=0xf4
unorestore.bootloader.file=Arduino-COMBINED-dfu-usbserial-atmega16u2-Mega2560-Rev3.hex
unorestore.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
unorestore.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0F
unorestore.build.mcu=atmega16u2
unorestore.build.f_cpu=16000000L
unorestore.build.board=uno.build.board=AVR_MEGA2560
unorestore.build.core=arduino:arduino
unorestore.build.variant=standard
```

**The problem is** after I upload a sketch (with a size say over 10 kB), I can't upload any new sketch and get this timeout error message instead as shown below. Not even a simple blink sketch. The TX and RX LED connected to the 16U2 uC that flashes during an sketch upload doesn't even blink once.

[image]

The only way I can get it take another sketch is to "re-flash" the bootloader on the 2560 uC via ArduinoISP. The TX and RX led now flashes during the sketch upload. Of course, this is a huge hassle as I don't want to do "re-flash" the 2560 bootloader every time I want to upload a sketch.

I don't have this problem on my Elegoo Mega2560 R3 clone board so I'm thinking it might be something wrong with my 16U2 firmware/bootloader. Anyone have any idea what else might be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Why are you compiling for the atmega16u2?

Comment: the first upload after flashing the bootloader doesn't require a reset to bootloader. following uploads require a reset before upload. does your auto-reset circuit work?

Comment: @Majenko that is the selection for burning the bootloader onto the ATMega16U2 via ArudinoISP.

Comment: @Juraj I never heard of this before. I pretty much copied the official schematic. Is the reset the same as pulling the reset pin on the 2560 to ground before the sketch upload?

Comment: You shouldn't be uploading a bootloader to the 16U2. You install the CDC/ACM firmware over DFU. Are you sure you aren't installing the 16U2 bootloader onto the Mega2560?

Comment: @Majenko I burned the "MEGA2560 16U2 Restore Firmware" to the ATMega16U2 uC and burned the "Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560" to the ATMega2560 uC. Both done via ArduinoISP. I double checked that I didn't get them flipped.

Comment: @Majenko I originally tried to use the ATmel Flip to flash the hex files for the Mega2560 to the 16U2. But for some reason, it won't accept the it but will accept the hex files for the UNO. So if I went with it, I'd have the computer recognize my mega as a uno

Comment: What exact file is it you are having to re-flash? The 16U2 CDC/ACM firmware or the ATMega2560 UART bootloader?

Comment: @Majenko the official hex file for the ATMega16U2 for the Mega2560 R3: "Arduino-COMBINED-dfu-usbserial-atmega16u2-Mega2560-Rev3.hex". It can be found here: https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/tree/master/firmwares/atmegaxxu2

Comment: @Majenko The "Arduino-COMBINED-dfu-usbserial-atmega16u2-Mega2560-Rev3.hex" file is what I burned to the 16U2 but can't be done via Atmel Flip software. The Arduino Mega2560 bootloader is what I have to re-flash in order to upload a new sketch as of now.

Comment: Ok. So why tell us all about the 16U2 when the problem bootloader is the 2560 one? It sounds like there may simply be a problem with your reset circuit rather than your firmwares. Try hitting reset on the board when attempting your second upload.

Comment: @Majenko I wasn't sure if it might be something to do with the 16U2 so I just put that info out there. I tried the reset to ground before hitting upload and it worked! I wonder what causing the reset issue. In the boards.txt file, the bootloader fuse line is "mega.menu.cpu.atmega2560.bootloader.high_fuses=0xD8" which is the correct default, isn't it?

Comment: That would make no difference. Please show us your schematic and board so we can examine the reset circuit for ourselves.

Comment: @Majenko Here is the EasyEDA share link: https://easyeda.com/salesagriculex/lcmr-v5 I'm comparing my schematic to the official eagle schematic right now to see if I missed anything.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to find my way around your schematic. I hate the modern way of having components with little labelled stubs instead of drawing proper nets linking things together. You can follow nets. You can't follow a little arrow and a name. And that EDA can't seem to do a simple search. So far all I have found for RST D7 on the 16U2, RESET on the 2560 and a pin on the ICSP. Are there other places where RST exists on that schematic?

Comment: Following the traces in the PCB layout editor it would appear not. Ok. I see a problem here.

Comment: @Majenko that should be all the RESET connections. I noticed on the official eagle schematics, there is circle between the REST net and the RESET pin on the 2560 chip.  The RESET pin on the 2560 also have the upper line above it.

Answer (score 1):

Your RESET circuit is wrong.

- You have no pullup resistor on the RESET pin of the ATMega3560.
- You have an extraneous pulldown resistor on the D7 pin of the 16U2.

That means your 16U2 will not be able to trigger a reset of the ATMega2560 to run the bootloader.

Remove the pulldown on D7 of the 16U2 and add a 10kΩ pullup to the RESET pin of the ATMega2560. Without that pullup:

1. The chip may not run properly as RESET is floating (it may have an internal pullup, I can't recall)
2. The capacitor linking the 16U2 D7 and RESET of the ATMega2560 won't be able to generate a proper reset pulse. This will be exacerbated by the 1kΩ pulldown.

On the Mega2560 reference schematic RN1A is the pullup in question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your find! Really appreciate it! I'll add the pull up resistor RN5A. As for the pull down resistor on D7 of the 16U2, it's from RN3D on the reference schematic. I'll remove that then. It said it's for USB Boot En.

Comment: I think that means it's for enabling DFU mode on the 16U2 - it may be related to why you can't use flip?

Comment: I was able to use the Flip software to upload the Uno hex file to a fresh new 16U2 but it can't just for the mega hex file. It said it was too large. Anyways, I added the pullup resistor and removed the pulldown resistor and it works now! I can upload a new code without having to re-flash the bootloader. You saved a huge amount of time for me. Would you accept a small tip via paypal if that's allowed? It's not much but as a way of thanks for your time.

Comment: Wow. If you really want to, sure. There's a "donate" link on UECIDE.org that goes to me if you really want to.

Comment: Majenko, I don't see a schematics in the question

Comment: @Juraj the link to it was posted under the comments of the original question post. The schematic itself has been turned private since the issue was solved.